# Time opertions using MomentJS

Tags: momentjs

I have fixed Date string, I would like to append time to it. one with current time  and the other with Current Time + 1 hour

Is this possible using MomentJS.

ex:

```
var startDate = moment("10/1/2014");
```

Now I would like to construct a new Date with StartDate with time (Logic mentioned above)

Comment: MomentJs is pretty well [documented](http://momentjs.com/docs/), what did you try?

Comment: In the docs, I didn't find any direct method to find current time

Comment: I think you misread: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by RC, you can do something like this:

```
var now = moment();
var plusHour = moment().add(1, 'h');
```

You can than format it like:

```
console.log(plusHour.format("YYYY-MM-DD h:m:s"))
```